# KDE Plasma: Skype messages opens up panel and won't close until clicked

Tags: skype, plasma, plasma5

I'm using KDE Plasma on ubuntu and I have aproblem with skype. Whenever someone messages me, the panel opens up and won't close until I read the message. Please take a look at these gifs:

In the first gif, you see, how the panels opens up, after I get a message, but the panel does not close.
[image]

In the second gif, you see, how I have to click on skype and to read the message, to close the panel.
[image]

How can I disable this behaviour? I don't want the panel to show up, everytime someone messages me. And I don't want to read the message, to close the panel.

Any suggestions? Please tell me, if you need more informations.

Plasma version:

```
$ plasmashell --version
plasmashell 5.8.5
```

EDIT: New skype version: Problem remains:
[image]